# createEntityManager() throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, jpa, junit, entitymanager

I have an application that runs on WildFly.

I need to write unit tests for the DAO objects and need an EntityManager. However, when calling `createEntityManager` on the EntityManagerFactory, I get an InvocationTargetException.

The test rung on a local MySQL server.

I'm out of ideas. Anyone know what may be wrong?

```
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test_fakebookPU");
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); // InvocationTargetException
```

persistence.xml

```
...
<!-- Persistence unit for testing ONLY-->
<persistence-unit name="test_myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>
        In memory example using Hibernate and HSQLDB
    </description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>se.chas.fakebook.entities.Post</class>
    <class>se.chas.fakebook.entities.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test_myPU"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="testuser"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="testpasss"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
...
```

Comment: add complete staktrace of your exception to the post.

Comment: Different PU names? test_fakebookPU != test_myPU